# Python XML - Create n SubElements

Tags: python, xml

How to create n SubElements? Number of elements was previously defined by the given value (count). Names of elements and values in them are the same for all elements. 
Example:

```
 <root>
      <selem>-9999</selem>
      <selem>-9999</selem>
      <selem>-9999</selem>
      <selem>-9999</selem>
              .
              .
              .
              n
 </root>
```

I tried something like the

```
 file_count = open('file_count.xml','r')
 data = file_count.read()
 file_count.close()
 dom = parseString(data)
 count = len(dom.getElementsByTagName('timePosition'))

 no_data = '-9999'
 top = etree.Element('root')
 children = [
     etree.SubElement(top, 'selem').text = no_data
     for i in xrange(count)
     ]
 top.extend(children)
 print etree.tostring(top)
 no_data_xml = etree.ElementTree(top)
 no_data_xml.write(new.xml')
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put statements such as variable assignments inside a list comprehension. Just use a plain for loop:

```
for i in xrange(count):
    elem = etree.SubElement(top, 'selem')
    elem.text = no_data
    top.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SubElement` automatically adds the element to it's parent, so no need for explicitly append/extend them. So no need to use a list comprehension, simply use a for-loop:

```
with open('file_count.xml','r') as file_count:
    data = etree.prase(file_count)
count = len(data.findall('.//timePosition'))

no_data = '-9999'
top = etree.Element('root')
for i in xrange(count):
    etree.SubElement(top, 'selem').text = no_data
 no_data_xml = etree.ElementTree(top)
 no_data_xml.write(new.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks. Only edit prase --> parse; for i in xrange(count) --> for i in xrange(count):